# Check if current site ID and value exist in WPDB

Tags: multisite, wpdb, domain-mapping

**How can I check the current site id against the database and do something?**

I'm trying to check if the current site id exists in the `WordPress MU Domain Mapping` plugin table. There are columns for `blog_id` and `active`. Ideally I would check *if* `blog_id` exists *and is* `active` then do something.

```
function is_domain_mapped() {
    global $wpdb;
    $domains = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT active FROM $wpdb->dmtable} WHERE blog_id  = %d", $blog_id );
        // Do Something
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'is_domain_mapped', -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should be able to map domains without 3rd party plugins.

Here's an untested suggestion for your callback in your current situation:

```
global $wpdb;

// Nothing to do if not multisite
if( ! is_multisite() )
    return;

// Define the custom table
$wpdb->dmtable = $wpdb->base_prefix . 'domain_mapping';

// Check if the custom table exists
if ( $wpdb->dmtable != $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$wpdb->dmtable}'" ) )
    return;

// Check if current site is mapped  
$domain_exists = (bool) $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT COUNT(blog_id) 
             FROM {$wpdb->dmtable} 
             WHERE blog_id = %d AND active = 1 LIMIT 0,1", 
        get_current_blog_id() 
    )
);

if( $domain_exists )
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That is wonderful!!!